# missing time range in a day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this:

```
create table time_sheet
(
      StatusCode char(1),
      start_time datetime,
      end_time datetime
)

insert into time_sheet values
('W','2012-08-01 10:00:00','2012-08-01 12:00:00'),
('D','2012-08-01 12:00:00','2012-08-01 14:00:00'),
('N','2012-08-01 16:00:00','2012-08-01 18:00:00')
```

The output should be like this:

```
StatusCode start_time               end_time
B          2012-08-01 08:00:00.000  2012-08-01 10:00:00.000
W          2012-08-01 10:00:00.000  2012-08-01 12:00:00.000
D          2012-08-01 12:00:00.000  2012-08-01 14:00:00.000
B          2012-08-01 14:00:00.000  2012-08-01 16:00:00.000
N          2012-08-01 16:00:00.000  2012-08-01 18:00:00.000
B          2012-08-01 18:00:00.000  2012-08-01 20:00:00.000
```

The beging and end of the day are declared as below.

```
declare @begingOfDay datetime='2012-08-01 08:00:00.000'
declare @endOfDay    datetime='2012-08-01 20:00:00.000'
```

Basically I want to have missing time range records in the result set between **begingOfDay**  and **endOfDay** with statusCode **B**   . Please see that in the output there are 3 records added with StatusCode B

Could anybody help with this?

Comment: this parameters are you passing from where in your query??

Comment: Are they always 2 hour ranges?

Comment: its better you use store procedure and then just pass that parameters

Comment: @JNK: NO, aways its not 2 hours

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: I tried something like 
select distinct 'B' as StatusCode,@begingOfDay as start_time,(select MIN(start_time) from time_sheet) end_time
from time_sheet
where DATEDIFF(MI,@begingOfDay,(select MIN(start_time) from time_sheet))>0 
     
     to get the first record and last record (with statusCode B) in the out put in the example. but i dont know how to get
     'in between' one with statusCode B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data (note, `T`s added to strings to enforce unambiguous date conversions):

```
create table time_sheet
(
      StatusCode char(1),
      start_time datetime,
      end_time datetime
)

insert into time_sheet values
('W','2012-08-01T10:00:00','2012-08-01T12:00:00'),
('D','2012-08-01T12:00:00','2012-08-01T14:00:00'),
('N','2012-08-01T16:00:00','2012-08-01T18:00:00')

declare @begingOfDay datetime='2012-08-01T08:00:00.000'
declare @endOfDay    datetime='2012-08-01T20:00:00.000'
```

And the query:

```
;with AllDTs as (
    select @begingOfDay as TimePoint
    union
    select @endOfDay
    union
    select start_time from time_sheet
    union
    select end_time from time_sheet
), OrderedDTs as (
    select TimePoint,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TimePoint) as rn
    from AllDTs
), Periods as (
    select o1.TimePoint as start_time,o2.TimePoint as end_time
    from
        OrderedDTs o1
            inner join
        OrderedDTs o2
            on
                o1.rn = o2.rn-1
)
select
    COALESCE(ts.StatusCode,'B') as StatusCode,
    p.start_time,
    p.end_time
from
    Periods p
        left join
    time_sheet ts
        on
            p.start_time = ts.start_time and
            p.end_time = ts.end_time
```

Result:

```
StatusCode start_time              end_time
---------- ----------------------- -----------------------
B          2012-08-01 08:00:00.000 2012-08-01 10:00:00.000
W          2012-08-01 10:00:00.000 2012-08-01 12:00:00.000
D          2012-08-01 12:00:00.000 2012-08-01 14:00:00.000
B          2012-08-01 14:00:00.000 2012-08-01 16:00:00.000
N          2012-08-01 16:00:00.000 2012-08-01 18:00:00.000
B          2012-08-01 18:00:00.000 2012-08-01 20:00:00.000
```

Note, I've proceeded on the assumption that there are no overlapping time periods in the original table. The first CTE (`AllDTs`) just finds all unique datetime values that are of interest to us. `OrderedDTs` and `Periods` than arrange all of these datetime values into successive periods. The final query then takes each of these periods, and attempts to match them back to the original table, if possible. If not, then it's obviously a `B` period.

Answer (score 1):

Try This one:

```
declare @begingOfDay datetime='2012-08-01 08:00:00.000'
declare @endOfDay    datetime='2012-08-01 20:00:00.000'




 declare @begingOfDay datetime='2012-08-01 08:00:00.000'
declare @endOfDay    datetime='2012-08-01 20:00:00.000'


;WITH CTEMain as (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 0)) as id,StatusCode,start_time,end_time from time_sheet)

,CTE2 as (
select * from (

select    CASE WHEN start_time > @begingOfDay then 'B' else StatusCode end as statusCode,
          CASE WHEN start_time > @begingOfDay then @begingOfDay else start_time end as start_time,
          CASE WHEN start_time > @begingOfDay then start_time else end_time end as end_time
          FROM CTEMain where id=1
UNION
select StatusCode,start_time,end_time from CTEMain 
union 

select 'B'
       ,CASE WHEN CAST(((select c.start_time from CTEMain c where c.id=t1.id+1)-t1.end_time) as time) > '00:00:00' then end_time  else null end as start_time
       ,CASE WHEN CAST(((select c.start_time from CTEMain c where c.id=t1.id+1)-t1.end_time) as time) > '00:00:00' then end_time+((select c.start_time from CTEMain c where c.id=t1.id+1)-t1.end_time)  else null end as start_time
     from CTEMain t1


     ) a)

select * from (  
select * from CTE2 where start_time is not null
union all
select 'B',CASE WHEN MAX(end_time) = @endOfDay then null else  MAX(end_time) end as start_time,@endOfDay as end_time from CTE2) a order by start_time
```